# Functional Override: What occurs and when

Tags: overriding, computer-science, discrete-mathematics

So, functional override and discrete mathematics. A feature I'm not entirely sure of in critical system design. Say we have a feature where if f() should fail; g() would override; as denoted below...

"**g() ⊕ f()**"

---

- x = 0.1;
- f(x) x^2     when x ∈ ℕ1,
- g(x) 2x -x   when x ∈ ℕ0

---

I understand that in a situation where the input (**x**) isn't within the scope or domain of **F()**, then function **G()** is supposed to act as it's override and **x** will become a function of **G()**, **g(x)**. But in the example above, you will notice that **x** is outside the domain of both **f()** and **g()**.

***So does this mean that the output is never given because x is an invalid input?***

This seems unlikely to be a realistic exception to have to deal with in a critical system as one would expect "**g() ⊕ f()**" to be capable of compensating for any input; but in a recent examination, this kind of question was given to me and I found it to be quite the trick question. If anyone could shed some light on this, it would be much appreciated; None of my books mention anything about handling this kind of input and all of the example which have been taught to me have always been instances where **x** is within the range/domain of at least **g()**.

Comment: As this question is defined, it is not suited to the tag [tag:safety-critical]. If the given example were ever implemented inside a safety-related system (say, according to IEC 61508), there would be the generic requirement, first to verify that input values are within the allowed range (and to perform a safety reaction). Therefore, the question is nice, but not in the scope of safety-related E/E/PE systems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that even with g() overriding f(), if the input is outside of the range of both the first and overriding function; the output is an error as it never qualifies for either test. Similarly when we try to factorise a negative number using a calculator.